# Difference of extremely large squares

Tags: number-theory

This was an extremely difficult question I've encountered in a practice Olympiad test, and I'm not just asking for the answer, I'm asking for the method of solving this and similar problems, so here's the gist:

Let $n$ be the number:

$$(\underbrace{777777777\ldots 777}_{4020~7\text{'s}})^2 - (\underbrace{888888888\ldots 888}_{4006~8\text{'s}})^2$$

So the aim of this question is to find the remainder when $n$ is divided by $11$

Can someone help me understand how to simplify this down and the method and steps for solving this and other similar problems since this might come up again and there is no use to me when I only know the answer and not the strategies involved in getting the answer, Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119275/discussion-on-question-by-alexjaynmf-difference-of-extremely-large-squares).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All numbers composed by an even number of repeated digit are divisible by $11$, so are their squares and obviously the difference between two of them.

Example. $7777=11\cdot 707, \;7777^2=11^2\cdot 707^2$

The answer is *zero*.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(\underbrace{777777777\ldots 777}_{4020~7\text{'s}})^2$ can be written as $S = \sum_{i=0}^{4020} 7 \cdot 10^i $.

Now, one can express $7 \cdot 10^i \text{ mod } 11$ as $7 \cdot (-1)^i$, since $10 = -1  \text{ mod } 11$. Now, replacing this in $S$ we obtain

$$S = \sum_{i=0}^{4020} 7 \cdot (-1)^i = 7 \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{4020} (-1)^i = 7 \cdot 0 = 0$$

One can argue the same for the second sum $F = (\underbrace{888888888\ldots 888}_{4006~8\text{'s}})$, and conclude that $$(\underbrace{777777777\ldots 777}_{4020~7\text{'s}})^2 - (\underbrace{888888888\ldots 888}_{4006~8\text{'s}})^2 = 0^2 - 0^2 \text{ mod } 11 = 0 \text{ mod } 11$$

Therefore, the remainder is $0$